# How I can Optimize this mySQL transaction within java code?

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design

I am new to MySql database. I've large table(ID,...). I select ID frequently with java code and.And that make a heavy load on transaction

```
 select from tableName where ID=someID
```

notes:

1.Database could be 100,000 records

2.I can't cache result

3.ID is a primary key
4.I try to optimize time needed to return result from query.

Any ideas for optimization ?

thanks in advance

Comment: @worldpython: I think you might need to be a bit more specific, if you expect good answers. Eg. how large is large, is ID a primary key, can you cache results, what are you trying to optimize (latency, the query itself), etc.?

Comment: And of course, how is the table indexed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considere partitioning? [Improving Database Performance with Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html).

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see the need to optimize. This is a simple query against a very tiny table in database terms and the item inthe where clause is a PK and thus indexed. This should run very fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the query to use a parameter, it might be a bit more efficient.  The server would not have to parse and semantic check the statement each time.

```
select * from tableName where ID = @someID
```

Then assign the parameter value for each execution.  [Here is an explanation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) of using prepared statements.

Comment: you means select from tableName where ID=someID &&more logic expression ??
thanks

Comment: @worldpython:  No.  Change it to be a parameterized query.  Maybe you are already doing that, but your example indicates that you are not.